# Infinity-Scroll [Wordpress, Origin Theme, Shadowbox Plugin]

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, infinite-scroll, shadowbox

I've never done Javascript,

On the website I've added rel="shadowbox" to the posts to pull up the lightbox of the post. The template has infinity-scroll built in and I've seen that you have to use a callback to make shadowbox work on the new posts. The problem is where do I put the code and how?

Example:

```
$("#container").on("focusin", function(){ $("a.ajaxFancyBox").fancybox({ // fancybox API options here 'padding': 0 }); // fancybox }); // on
```

Do I put this in the head in a script tag?

Answer (score 0):

You could include it in the head of your website if you'd like... something like this may work for you:

```
<script>
$(function(){

    $("#container").on("focusin", function(){ $("a.ajaxFancyBox").fancybox({ 
         // fancybox API options here 'padding': 0 
        }); // fancybox 
    }); 

});
</script>
```

If you're not so much a programmer and want a top-notch modal plugin (lightbox), I suggest checking out Easy Fancybox.  It works and looks great.  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-fancybox/

Comment: I tried Easy Fancybox, with the above code in the header. :( I don't know what I could be doing wrong. the site I'm working on is (http://terryhaywood.co.za/)

Comment: Using Firebug Console I'm getting "TypeError: $ is not a function", if I add jQuery in manually to the template header this does load with no errors but clicking on the link gives the error ".fancybox is not a function” but that is because of the double jQuery. PS: the above is loading after the jquery lib from google.

Answer (score 0):

Scratch that, Took Shadowbox & Easy FancyBox out completely.

Used Wordpress Built in Thickbox

Above the post added

```
<?php add_thickbox(); ?>
```

add a class

```
class="thickbox"
```

At the end of the link added because it was an iframe

```
?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=400&width=600
```

Which I think does it's own callback (I Can't find if I put it in)
If so add the following to the header.php

```
<script> tb_init( $('a.thickbox, area.thickbox, input.thickbox',this) );</script>
```

Like I said I don't think it needs it.

Thanks for your help though.